# PHP: Loading multiple XML feeds with simple_xml_load_file

Tags: php, simplexml

I'm retrieving multiple weather forecasts through Yahoo's weather API -

```
$stockholm = simplexml_load_file("http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?w=906057&u=c");
$stockholm->registerXpathNamespace('yweather', 'http://xml.weather.yahoo.com/ns/rss/1.0'); 
$children = $stockholm->xpath('//channel/item/yweather:condition'); 
echo '<li><img class="c' . $children[0]['code'] . '" src="img/spacer.gif" alt=""><h2>' . $children[0]['temp'] . '&deg;</h2><p><strong>Stockholm</strong></p></li>';

$alicante = simplexml_load_file("http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?w=752101&u=c");
$alicante->registerXpathNamespace('yweather', 'http://xml.weather.yahoo.com/ns/rss/1.0'); 
$children = $alicante->xpath('//channel/item/yweather:condition'); 
echo '<li><img class="c' . $children[0]['code'] . '" src="img/spacer.gif" alt=""><h2>' . $children[0]['temp'] . '&deg;</h2><p><strong>Alicante</strong></p></li>';

$marbella = simplexml_load_file("http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?w=766537&u=c");
$marbella->registerXpathNamespace('yweather', 'http://xml.weather.yahoo.com/ns/rss/1.0'); 
$children = $marbella->xpath('//channel/item/yweather:condition'); 
echo '<li><img class="c' . $children[0]['code'] . '" src="img/spacer.gif" alt=""><h2>' . $children[0]['temp'] . '&deg;</h2><p><strong>Marbella</strong></p></li>';

$torrevieja = simplexml_load_file("http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?w=775868&u=c");
$torrevieja->registerXpathNamespace('yweather', 'http://xml.weather.yahoo.com/ns/rss/1.0'); 
$children = $torrevieja->xpath('//channel/item/yweather:condition'); 
echo '<li><img class="c' . $children[0]['code'] . '" src="img/spacer.gif" alt=""><h2>' . $children[0]['temp'] . '&deg;</h2><p><strong>Torrèvieja</strong></p></li>';
```

Is there a more effective way to load these feeds, possibly together? The response time is fairly minimal but if there's any way this could be optimized I'd like to know.

Comment: Why not use simplexml_load_string?

Answer (score 2):

This does the same, but looks a bit more elegeant

```
<?php

$xml = array('stockholm' => 906057, 'alicante' => 752101, 'marbella' => 766537, 'torrevieja' => 775868);

foreach($xml as $city => $code) {
    $smplxml = simplexml_load_file('http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?w=' .$code. '&u=c');
    $smplxml->registerXpathNamespace('yweather', 'http://xml.weather.yahoo.com/ns/rss/1.0');
    $children = $smplxml->xpath('//channel/item/yweather:condition'); 
    echo '<li><img class="c' . $children[0]['code'] . '" src="img/spacer.gif" alt=""><h2>' . $children[0]['temp'] . '&deg;</h2><p><strong>' .$city. '</strong></p></li>';
}

?>
```

(since I'm behind a proxy right now, I wasn't able to test it, sorry, but it may helps)

Comment: cURL supports proxy, just in case.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not sure it helped in decreasing the load speed for the actual feeds but using the array really cleaned up the code.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you did something like:

```
function curlGet( $url ) {
   $ch = curl_init(); 
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
   $output = curl_exec($ch); 

   curl_close($ch); 

   return $output;
}

$xml = array('stockholm' => 906057, 'alicante' => 752101, 'marbella' => 766537, 'torrevieja' => 775868);

$buffer = "<rsses>";

foreach($xml as $city => $code)
  $buffer .= curlGet('http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?w=' .$code. '&u=c');

$buffer .= "</rsses>";

$smplxml = simplexml_load_string($buffer);
$smplxml->registerXpathNamespace('yweather', 'http://xml.weather.yahoo.com/ns/rss/1.0');
$children = $smplxml->xpath('//rss/channel/item/yweather:condition'); 

print_r($children);
```

Might work. You need to make sure that the data you add to $buffer is not junk though. Or otherwise your entire parsing will fail.